# How to efficiently merge these data.tables

Tags: r, performance, memory, data.table

I want to create a certain data.table to be able to check for missing data.
Missing data in this case does not mean there will be an NA, but the entire row will just be left out. So I need to be able to see of a certain time dependent column which values are missing for which level from another column. Also important is if there are a lot of missing values together or if they are spread across the dataset.

So I have this 6.000.000x5 data.table (Call it TableA) containing the time dependent variable, an ID for the level and the value N which I would like to add to my final table.

I have another table (TableB) which is 207x2. This couples the ID's for the factor to the columns in TableC.

TableC is 1.500.000x207 of which each of the 207 columns correspond to an ID according to TableB and the rows correspond to the time dependent variable in TableA.

These tables are large and although I recently acquired extra RAM (totalling now to 8GB) my computer keeps swapping away TableC and for each write it has to be called back, and gets swapped away again after. This swapping is what is consuming all my time. About 1.6 seconds per row of TableA and as TableA has 6.000.000 rows this operation would take more than a 100 days running non stop..

Currently I am using a for-loop to loop over the rows of TableA. Doing no operation this for-loop loops almost instantly. I made a one-line command looking up the correct column and row number for TableC in TableA and TableB and writing the value from TableA to TableC.
I broke up this one-liner to do a system.time analysis and each step takes about 0 seconds except writing to the big TableC.
This showed that writing the value to the table was the most time consuming and looking at my memory use I can see a huge chunk appearing whenever a write happens and it disappears as soon as it is finished.

```
TableA <- data.table("Id"=round(runif(200, 1, 100)), "TimeCounter"=round(runif(200, 1, 50)), "N"=round(rnorm(200, 1, 0.5)))
TableB  <- data.table("Id"=c(1:100),"realID"=c(100:1))
TSM <- matrix(0,ncol=nrow(TableB), nrow=50)
TableC <- as.data.table(TSM)
rm(TSM)
for (row in 1:nrow(TableA))
{
  TableCcol <- TableB[realID==TableA[row,Id],Id]
  TableCrow <- (TableA[row,TimeCounter])
  val <- TableA[row,N]
  TableC[TableCrow,TableCcol] <- val
}
```

Can anyone advise me on how to make this operation faster, by preventing the memory swap at the last step in the for-loop?

---

Edit: On the advice of @Arun I took some time to develop some dummy data to test on. It is now included in the code given above.
I did not include wanted results because the dummy data is random and the routine does work. It's the speed that is the problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem, along with the solution you require. There's just too much text to follow ATM.

Comment: I can provide some code, but no data. Also how can I produce a reproducible example of a memory problem?

Comment: Let me think.. You could provide code for generating a small dataset of your tables. Then show us what your code is. Then show us the result from that code. Then explain that this doesn't scale to your data dimensions. Then ask how you could resolve the memory issue. Also, you say memory issue, and you end your post with "how can I make this operation faster?".

Comment: Maybe you should read the rest of my question :)
The slowness is because of a memory swap issue.

Comment: You're right. I'll let someone else take over. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rethinking my problem I came to a solution which works much faster.
The thing is that it does not follow from the question posed above, because I already did a couple of steps to come to the situation described in my question.

Enter TableX from which I aggregated TableA. TableX contains Id's and TimeCounters and much more, that's why I thought it would be best to create a smaller table containing only the information I needed.
TableX also contains the relevant times while in my question I am using a complete time series from the beginning of time (01-01-1970 ;) ). It was way smarter to use the levels in my TimeCounter column to build my TableC.

Also I forced myself to set values individually while merging is a lot faster in data.table. So my advice is: **whenever you need to set a lot of values try finding a way to merge instead of just copying them individually.**

Solution:

```
# Create a table with time on the row dimension by just using the TimeCounters we find in our original data.
TableC <- data.table(TimeCounter=as.numeric(levels(factor(TableX[,TimeCounter]))))
setkey(TableC,TimeCounter) # important to set the correct key for merge.

# Loop over all unique Id's (maybe this can be reworked into something *apply()ish)
for (i in levels(factor(TableX[,Id])))
{
  # Count how much samples we have for Id and TimeCounter
  TableD <- TableX[Id==i,.N,by=TimeCounter]
  setkey(TableD,TimeCounter) # set key for merge
  # Merge with Id on the column dimension
  TableC[TableD,paste("somechars",i,sep=""):=N]
}
```

There could be steps missing in the TimeCounter so now I have to check for gaps in TableC and insert rows which were missing for all Id's. Then I can finally check where and how big my data gaps are.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about the results, but give it a shot with the dplyr/tidyr packages for, as they seem to be more memory efficient than for loops.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("tidyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

TableC <- TableC %>% gather(tableC_id, value, 1:207)
```

This turns TableC from 1,500,000x207 to a long format 310,500,000x2 table with 'tableC_id' and 'tableC_value' columns.

```
TableD <- TableA %>% 
    left_join(TableB, c("LevelID" = "TableB_ID")) %>% 
    left_join(TableC, c("TableB_value" = "TableC_id")
```

This is a couple of packages I've been using of late, and they seem to be very efficient, but the data.table package is used specifically for management of large tables so there could be useful functions there. I'd also take a look at sqldf which allows you to query your data.frames via SQL commands.